# remove Google's App verification notification in Android x86 in VMWare

Tags: android, vmware, android-x86, vmware-player

IF I try to run my code on the Android x86 installed in VMWare player, when the first time the app is run for the first time, for most of the apps it shows a notification as shown below:
[image].
If I click decline the notification goes away but the app doesn't run. It runs only when I run my code again, and sometimes the app runs even with the notification anyway. Is there any way I can disable this notification completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to stop verifying applications at any time, go to Google Settings > Verify apps, then touch the box to remove the check mark. For devices running Android 4.2 and higher, you can also go to Settings > Security > Verify apps. Make sure you save your snapshot on VMware so this setting is saved.